# How to print EE ui.Chart to to file?

Tags: google-earth-engine

May be the first question is, can I print ui.Chart to file, e.g. PNG? And then how?

Here is what I tried

https://code.earthengine.google.com/4fef1d985ce0727c1f83226fbc5417fa